# 2D array to populate combobox

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am trying to populate a combobox from 2D array. I want it the first dimension to be assigned as DisplayMember values, and the second as ValueMemeber. Have been looking online, but I could not find a solution that would work for me. Below is the code that I am trying to use. This does not work.

```
string[,] Options = new string[3, 2]{
        {"Invoice", "3"},
        {"Group Invoice", "4"},
        {"Group Invoice BUCKS", "5"} };

cboOption.DataSource = Options;
```

I have tried using a for loop and it does not work either and I get this error message: "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set." Example below:

```
string[,] Options = new string[3, 2]{
        {"Invoice", "3"},
        {"Group Invoice", "4"},
        {"Group Invoice BUCKS", "5"} };

cboOption.DisplayMember = "Text";
cboOption.ValueMember = "Key";

for (int i = 0; i < Options.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    cboOption.Items.Add(new { Text = Options[i, 0], Key=Convert.ToInt16(Options[i, 1]) });
}
```

Can I do that? If I can could you give me an example.

Thank you

Comment: What is the project type? Widows Form, WPF, ASP.NET or...

Comment: place cboOption.DisplayMember = "Text";
cboOption.ValueMember = "Key";
after the for

Comment: @Lidaranis I have tried that same error: "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a control databound, you do not add items to the control, you add them to the bound datasource. Instead of adding items to `cboOption.Items`, add them to the collection that your control is bound to. In your case however, you have an array. You would be better off rewriting that array into a resizable collection or datatable.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have tried this?.. this is a paste straight from vs and it's working

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[,] Options = new string[3, 2]{
        {"Invoice", "3"},
        {"Group Invoice", "4"},
        {"Group Invoice BUCKS", "5"} };



        for (int i = 0; i < Options.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            cboOption.Items.Add(new { Text = Options[i, 0], Key = Convert.ToInt16(Options[i, 1]) });
        }

        cboOption.DisplayMember = "Text";
        cboOption.ValueMember = "Key";
    }
```

Comment: Oh yes, it does I had DisplayMember and ValueMember set with Text and Key in the properties of combobox for some reason. Removed them and it  works fine. Thank you!

Comment: I opened the form next time and it has DisplayMember set as (none). And throws same error message.

Comment: As i said, this is tested. It seems that you might have other problems on the form, but to be honest the solution you found is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gmiley for the advise. After trying all the different options came up with a solution.

So I created a class Options instead of the array

```
    public class Options
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I used the code below to populate combobox

```
        var items = new List<Options>
        {
            new Options() { Name="Invoice", Value=3},
            new Options() { Name="Group Invoice", Value=4},
            new Options() { Name="Group Invoice BUCKS", Value=5},
        };

        cboOption.DataSource = items;
        cboOption.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cboOption.ValueMember = "Value";
```